# Learning to write Chaincode on hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

What are some good resources to start from to learn to write chaincodes for Hyperedger Fabric platform after https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode.
I wanted to make a decentralized app that stores rows of data taking input from multiple peers and incorporating them into one central ledger from where data can be looked up. I feel lost proceeding to write the chaincode considering I couldnt find much resources or examples online. I'd really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official [Getting Started](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) documentation pages, updated daily. Also there is a youtube [channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCFdgCWH_1vCndMPVqQlwZw) with different tutorials which you might find useful. Finally you have [examples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/examples/chaincode/go) on github.

PS. For more information you can join [Rocket.Chat](https://chat.hyperledger.org/home) and ask more specific questions there.

Answer (score 0):

The best source I've found to contemplate the blockchain innovation and get a pleasant perspective of the entire thing at the present time is utilizing the white papers from an essential infrastructure start-ups in the blockchain community.

In the event that you are beginning, you should realize that there is a great deal of buzz about blockchain innovation. There tons of alternatives conceptually different each one from another. I would state an ideal approach to begin is seeing how Blockchain functions.

There is an open source Blockchain project called Hyperledger Fabric that is super easy to setup on your portable PC, utilizing docker or vagrant to begin learning and coding. It accompanies all source code including protocol code to make them go.

Here are assets to kick you off:

1. At the [IBM Blockchain 101](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-ibm-blockchain-101-quick-start-guide-for-developers-bluemix-trs/index.html): A snappy starting guide which will demonstrate to you best practices to setup blockchain arrange (on your portable PC) where you can create, test, and deploy your blockchain chain code.
2. At [IBM Blockchain site](https://www.ibm.com/blockchain/) it will demonstrate to you accepted methods to rapidly run a Fabric blockchain network in a protected cloud condition to play around with.